# how to import data from text file into MYSQL database table?

Tags: php, mysql, import

i am trying to import data from a text file into my mysql database table. Some how data is imported but its not the correct data. Also i get this error:

Undefined offset: 6 in C:\wamp\www\Upload\main.php on line 36
Please review my code.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hiren");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }


    $f = fopen("./uploads/imp.txt", "r");
    while(!feof($f)) { 
      $data = explode(" ", fgets($f));

      $id =$data[0];
       $emp_id = $data[1];
       $date = $data[2];
       $abc = $data[3];
       $def = $data[4];
       $entry = $data[5];
       $ghi = $data[6];

       mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `daily_data2` (emp_id, date, abc, def, entry, ghi) 
    VALUES ('$emp_id', '$date', '$abc', '$def', '$entry', '$ghi')") or die(mysql_error());

        }

        fclose($f);

        ?>
```

**My Table :**

[image: mytable]

The Imp.txt file:

[image: text file]

the Data is inserted in this manner which is wrong :[image: uploaded data]]

The error i am getting:
[image: error]

Comment: `print_r($data)` and add the response if `print_r()`.

Comment: what is inside `imp.txt` post it in you question so we will be able to help you

Comment: please post how the data looks

Comment: `Undefined offset: 6` means, that in you im.txt no column nr. 7.

Comment: @Armen updated the question please check

Comment: just one more additional question about imp.txt between `1  2015-11-04 13:29:32` you have tabulation  `\t` ? or many spaces (if spaces then how many of them) ?

Comment: its a one tab between the data

Comment: there is /t in between them

Comment: you are passing 6 columns in the file and trying to access 7 indices when you explode the data. Don't see how it will work.

Comment: i have removed the 7th indice as id the error is solved but data is not correct it seems it inserted dump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i guess this will solve your problem

```
$handle = fopen("./uploads/imp.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

         $lineArr = explode("\t", "$line");
         var_dump($lineArr); // to make sure array is ok

         // instead assigning one by onb use php list -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php            
         list($emp_id, $date, $abc, $def, $entry, $ghi) = $lineArr;

         // and then insert data
         mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `daily_data2` (emp_id, date, abc, def, entry, ghi) 
VALUES ('$emp_id', '$date', '$abc', '$def', '$entry', '$ghi')");
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: $emp_id=$data[0]... all that as it is?

Comment: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\wamp\www\Upload\test.php on line 18

Comment: post pls what you after var_dump($lineArr);

Comment: i have posted it in my question

Comment: updated the question did 
       var_dump($lineArr);

Comment: ok my bad i placed `id` at the beginning `list`, check it now i fixed it

Comment: all error solved but the main thing that the data is not inserted into database  :(

Comment: try to exec that query manually in phpmyadmin -> INSERT INTO `daily_data2` (emp_id, date, abc, def, entry, ghi) 
VALUES ('1', '2015-05-05 05:05:05', '1', '0', '101', '0') see what happens

Comment: Thanks its working it was my mistake as i had changed the date to date_data in fields thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

The error shows like, for some row, there is no data available in the 6th index which you should pass the null string like the below code.
Note: Hope each rows splitted using " " by which you are trying to explode but this is not a good practice because if any of the data contains space which also considers as a new row. 
Update your code like this:

```
   $data = explode(" ", fgets($f));

   $id = !empty($data[0]) ? $data[0] : '';
   $emp_id = !empty($data[1]) ?$data[1] : '';
   $date = !empty($data[2]) ? $data[2] : '';
   $abc = !empty($data[3]) ? $data[3] : '';
   $def = !empty($data[4]) ? $data[4] : '';
   $entry = !empty($data[5]) ? $data[5] : '';
   $ghi = !empty($data[6]) ? $data[6] : '';
```

Comment: So i have not passed anything for my id  can that be the reason?

Comment: You have to at least pass a null string ('') even if the id is empty. Otherwise  don't use id if you don't need to pass, Hope that is an automatic increment field. So ignore the id.

Comment: Then index starts from $emp_id = !empty($data[0]) ?$data[0] : '';

Comment: Okay i have ignored the id

Comment: but my data is inserted in wrong way now i mean the date in not getting inserted in date filed

Comment: please check the updated question i have added how my data is inserted

Answer (score 1):

you have to index more fields than they get as a result

You index  7 fields but you have only 6 fields

```
 $data = explode(" ", fgets($f));   // this give you 6 value but you index 7

 $id =$data[0];
   $emp_id = $data[1];
   $date = $data[2];
   $abc = $data[3];
   $def = $data[4];
   $entry = $data[5];
   $ghi = $data[6];

   mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `daily_data2` (emp_id, date, abc, def, entry, ghi) 
VALUES ('$emp_id', '$date', '$abc', '$def', '$entry', '$ghi')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: please check the updated question i have added how my data is inserted

Comment: the data is inserted in wrong manner what could be the possible reason i have removed the id and that solved the issue but data is not inserted properly

Answer (score 1):

string fgets ( resource $handle [, int $length ] )

Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, or a newline (which is included in the return value), or an EOF (whichever comes first). If no length is specified, it will keep reading from the stream until it reaches the end of the line.

so use:

`$data = explode(" ", trim(fgets($f,4096)));`

also use 
`ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);`
before fopen

Comment: please check the updated question i have added how my data is inserted